# 敬遠の使い方について (how to use the expression 敬遠)

Tags: word-usage

## 日本語

クリスマスプレゼントとして、『日本酒辞典』という本をもらいました。読んでいると、以下の文が出てきました：

> (前略)ついつい頼んでしまったり、気になるけど注文しづらくて敬遠している、なんて人もいるでしょう。

理解できていると思うのですが、[国語辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/66037/meaning/m0u/)と[外国人のjdict](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%95%AC%E9%81%A0)で「敬遠」を調べてみたところ、どのセンスがあてはまるか分からないです。

本文の定義としては、「難しいと思って、回避する」だと思います。

私が勘違いしているのでしょうか。

## English

As a Christmas present, I received "日本酒辞典." While reading, I encountered the following sentence:

> ... ついつい頼んでしまったり、気になるけど注文しづらくて敬遠している、なんて人もいるでしょう。

I think I understand the sentence but the use of 敬遠 does not seem to match up well with either [goo](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/66037/meaning/m0u/) or [外国人のjdict](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%95%AC%E9%81%A0)'s definitions for 「敬遠」.

I think it means to avoid because you find it daunting.

Am I misunderstanding the usage here?

Comment: For clarification, you are unsure because the "finding the thing daunting" that you think is implicit in the meaning of "敬遠" in the quote seems to be at odds with the goo辞書's characterization of the motivation for avoidance (i.e. "かかわりを持つことを嫌って") and jisho's specification about that which is avoided ( i.e. "something unpleasant"), am I correct?

Comment: Yes, since neither of those make much sense at least on how I read the sentence in question. Or else I don't understand that use of 嫌って (which seems mirrored in in the JDICT translation of "unpleasant").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to cases where you do find someone/something unpleasant, you can use "敬遠" to describe situations where you avoid someone/something for other, less negative reasons.

One such reason would be that you consider the person as being out your league, that you are no match for them. Another would be that you find the thing alright, or even desirable, but the path you must take to get to it is not.

So, in the case of JDICT, to define "敬遠" simply and singly as "avoiding (something unpleasant)" would be to define it too narrowly, though not outright wrongly.

In fairness to them, however, I must mention that they also give the less-specifying second gloss "shy away from", presumably in order to counteract the over-specification of the first, or at least to properly widen the coverage. We would be wrong to judge them based on (the bad) half of the evidence.

As for goo辞書's case, I think "かかわりを持つことを嫌ってその物事を避けること。" leaves no room for fault-finding.

Unlike JDICT's "avoiding (something unpleasant)", this does not say the avoided entity is found dislikable (I fear "dislikable" might be too strong a word for "嫌って" here), but it's the *having to do with it* that it says is found dislikable.

And they would be right in this claim. "敬遠" does not entail that the avoider has a distaste for the avoided, but it is, I think, necessarily true that they find the experience that comes with having or being with or getting to it/them disagreeable or at least uncomfortable. This is the case even in situations where the person/thing being kept a distance from is regarded positively in some way. A couple of examples:

- 男子たちは彼女を高嶺の花だと思って敬遠している。

This sentence means the boys hold the girl in high estimation, but they don't feel comfortable at the prospect of dating her, or possibly talking to her or possibly, even, literally getting near her, because they think she is too good for them and they would feel like dirt next to her.

- このカフェには興味があったけど駅から遠いので今まで敬遠していた。

This means you've been interested in the cafe, but the travel there seemed like too much of a hassle to you so you've never popped in, until now.

The last example reminds me that 敬遠 doesn't always involve active avoidance, suggesting that translations like "avoid" (which I believe carries the connotation of activeness) might not fit the word's meaning sometimes.

Lastly and most importantly, about your interpretation of the use of the word in the quote. I can't say I'm absolutely certain, but I do tend to agree the text is commenting that there are probably some people who find sake (or some particular sake?) so daunting that they avoid it. At the least it is not indicating by the use of "敬遠" that said people avoid (some particular) sake because they find it unpleasant.

So in conclusion, I will say that your interpretation of the word, as I hope I've somehow managed to show, is entirely acceptable, and is not (entirely) at odds with the dictionaries' accounts of its meaning and usage.

Answer (score 5):

「難しいと思って回避する」 is a good interpretation of the sentence, and reflects a common connotation of the word 敬遠-する.

Actually, 日本国語大辞典 (a larger dictionary) has 「また，単に人や物事を避けること」 as a meaning. You can simply understand it as "to avoid", but I *feel* that it's usually used for avoiding something but understanding at the same time that it is valuable (at least potentially) or that it is appreciated elsewhere.

Searching google for [敬遠しがち](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E6%95%AC%E9%81%A0%E3%81%97%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A1%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) might give you some examples of similar usage.

Comment: @Yoshの答えかGoldbrickの答えを選ぶのが迷っていましたが、具体的例いっぱい入れてくれて、Goldbrickの方にしました。本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: @virmaior 僕もあちらの答えのほうが詳細で細かいニュアンスを伝えていると思います．わざわざコメント下さってありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

> (A) 気になるけど注文しづらくて**敬遠している**
>
> (B) 本文の定義として、「**難しくてと思って**、回避する」と思います。

(A)の中での「敬遠する」の解釈として(B)は合っていると思います。

質問者が示した国語辞典及び外国人向けの辞典jisho.orgの各々３つの定義を文末に示しますが、「敬遠（する）」に対する各々の定義は一見異なっているように見えますが、その違いは適用される場面や対象による違いであって本質的には同じことを述べています。

すなわち、

> 「**敬遠する**」とは
>   ある行為を実施した場合とその行為をしない場合の損得勘定をして（メリットとデメリットを天秤にかけ）、ある行為を実施しない方がメリットが大きいと推量/判断して実施しない方を選ぶ、あるいは行為を避ける、あるいは対象と接触することを避ける/遠ざける

ことだと思います。

「損になる場合の理由（デメリット）」は、文脈やこれまでの経験から明記/明示されないことが一般ですが、与えられた例文では、「注文しづらい」と **損になる状況（デメリット）** を明記しております。

「注文しづらい」にも色々な場合がありますが、例えば「インターネットでの注文方法やお金の支払い方法が難しい」のか、あるいは「注文時に色々な記入すべきことや提供すべき情報が多いので面倒である」のか、更に、「注文に際して、予め調べないと提供できない情報が含まれていたり、クッキーの使用を承諾しなければならないなどすぐには購入判断がしづらい」のかもしれません。いずれにせよ、「注文に際して難しいことが多い」と解釈すれば質問者の解釈は合っていると判断できます。

国語辞典

> 敬遠
>   ［名］(スル)
>   １ 表面では敬う態度で、実際にはかかわりを持たないようにすること。「口うるさいので周囲から敬遠される」
>   ２ かかわりを持つことを嫌ってその物事を避けること。「めんどうな仕事を敬遠する」
>   ３ 野球で、投手が打者との勝負を避け、故意に四球を与えること。「強打者を敬遠する」

Jisho.org

> 敬遠
>   Noun, Suru verb
>   1. pretending to respect someone while in fact staying distant; keeping at arms length; giving a wide berth
>   2. avoiding (something unpleasant); shying away from​
>   3. giving the batter an "intentional walk"​Baseball term

---

## EDIT

> 気になるけど注文しづらくて敬遠している

最初の回答で「注文する方法が難しい」ような意味で「敬遠」を解釈しましたが、与えられた文が「日本酒」に関する本の中に登場する文だとすると全く違う解釈もできます。

文章を書いた人が日本酒が大変好きである。しかし、「獺祭｛だっさい｝」のようなおいしいと評判が高いが高価なお酒の購入を迷っているのかもしれない。この人は、結婚しており、奥さんからは「あんたは、いつもお酒ばかり飲んで...」と小言を言われている。
そうすると、質問者が提示した(A)で示した文は、「獺祭は買いたいが奥さんは怖いは」と言う意味で購入を躊躇している気持ちを表した文かもしれません。その場合は、「奥さんが怖くて購入を躊躇している」と言う意味の「敬遠」の場合もあります。その場合メリットは「美味しいお酒」、ディメリットは「高価な値段が少しと、奥さんの怖い顔が大半」で、ディメリットの方がメリットより大きいと推察されますので「敬遠している」のかもしれません。

Comment: 編集部分は面白くいのが、編集する前の解釈はほぼあてます。